# iPhone 6+ mobile safari landscape with mulitple tabs open and bootstrap modal hides immediately after open

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari, iphone-6-plus

I am facing problem in bootstrap modal with iPhone safari 6+ landscape mode. This bug occurs only in iPhone 6+ landscape mode with multiple tab open in safari browser.

Below are the step to generate the bug. 
1) Goto http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ on your iPhone 6+ in landscape mode - **be sure you must open multiple tab** 
2) Scroll down the page and click on "Small Modal" button in Optional size section.
3) You can notice that modal is opening and closed immediately in flash and grey background remain as it is. You can't do any clicks now.
4) Now, try to hide the Nav-bar and tab bar manually by scrolling up the page. It will show the bootstrap modal as expected. But it's not working when it open with multiple tab open in browser.

After doing some work around I think the problem is in `.modal-open`

```
.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

I have to find a work around for the problem. Any suggestion, ideas?

Comment: Which property bugs Safari?? Is it the overflow hidden? the fixed property? or the width property?

Comment: I will be able to provide a solution to work around the overflow hidden and width property, but I believe it would be near to impossible to make a work around the fixed property.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think bug is in fixed properly, because when I remove this property bootstrap modal it's not working at all.

Comment: To replace the fixed property with pure javascript is miles beyond my skill level in javascript.

Comment: Do you mind if I post an answer to work around overflow hidden property? Also does this work in other browsers? Chrome, Firefox mobile, or Opera?

Comment: no problem, give me some work around on overflow hidden property, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Alright, please forgive me though. This will take awhile.

Comment: tabs open as separate window in chorme and firefox, so it's work as expected in both browser.

Comment: I'm sorry @Ankit I have tried my best to work around overflow and I have had no luck whatsoever.

Comment: Even if I were to find a way it would be horribly  bulky and complicated and your html would have to be littered with divs and spans. Moreover it would dramatically increase the load time of your web page.

Comment: No problem, @HTMLNoob . thanks for your effort. Will let you know if I found any workaround...

Answer (score 0):

I was too late to give an answer, but anyone who having same issue like I am facing then I have some workaround on this.

First of all this bug in bootstrap. It's bootstrap bug for iPhone 6+ multi tab issue.

Ref link `https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/18859`

But for me I want the solution anyhow, so I made some changes in my style sheet and this solution works for me. Hope anyone who is facing same issue may get help form this.

```
 /*for iphone 6+ multitab issue  */
    .modal {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }
```

This few lines of style sheet solve my problem. I don't know that munch about CSS and style sheet but this is how I solved it.